# I have a simple blog website, if i add posts or edit posts , and go to home page state in which posts are stored is not saved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

i am writing code for blog website, each user will have posts. i get the token from server which contains user id and posts. everything works ok but when i add new post or edit posts, state is not saved. posts go back to the value at which user logged in. posts are updated in posts page, but when i go to home page/dashboard posts are not saved. can someone tell me the solution?

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/dashboard/Home";
import About from "./components/about/About";
import Contact from "./components/about/Contact";
import Post from "./components/post/Post";
import Error500 from "./components/errors/Error500";
import Error404 from "./components/errors/Error404";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/auth/ForgotPassword";
import AddPost from "./components/post/AddPost";
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer";
import Header from "./components/layout/Header";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import setAuthToken from "./utils/setAuthToken";
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from "./actions/authActions";
import { setPosts } from "./actions/postActions";
import store from "./store";

// Check for token to keep user logged in
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  // Set user,posts and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded.id));
  store.dispatch(setPosts(decoded.posts));
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/";
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuthenticated);

  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/forgot" component={ForgotPassword} />
        <NavRoute
          exact
          path="/users/:userId/home"
          component={Home}
          authed={auth}
        />
        <NavRoute exact path="/about" component={About} authed={auth} />
        <NavRoute exact path="/contact" component={Contact} authed={auth} />
        <NavRoute
          exact
          path="/users/:userId/posts/:postId"
          component={Post}
          authed={auth}
        />
        <NavRoute
          exact
          path="/users/:userId/addPost"
          component={AddPost}
          authed={auth}
        />
        <Route exact path="/Error500" component={Error500} />
        <Route path="*" component={Error404} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
}

const NavRoute = ({ exact, path, authed, component: Component }) => (
  <Route
    exact={exact}
    path={path}
    render={(props) =>
      authed === false ? (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Component {...props} />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )
    }
  />
);
```

following is the code for Post.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Icon } from "@material-ui/core";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import { useStyles } from "../../materialUI/materialUI";
import { Redirect, useHistory, useParams } from "react-router";
import { deletePost, editPost } from "../../actions/postActions";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getUser } from "../dashboard/Home";
import { getErrors } from "../auth/Register";
import { confirm } from "../../confirmAlert/confirmAlert";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { saveErrors } from "../../actions/authActions";

export default function Post() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [editClicked, setEditClicked] = useState(false);
  const [post, setPost] = useState({ title: "", content: "" });

  const { postId } = useParams();
  const { posts } = useSelector(getUser);
  const history = useHistory();
  const errors = useSelector(getErrors);

  useEffect(() => {
    const selectedPost = posts.find((post) => postId === post._id);
    if (selectedPost) return setPost(selectedPost);
    saveErrors({ postDoesNotexist: "post does not exist" });
  }, [posts, postId]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setPost((prevVal) => {
      return { ...prevVal, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  const handleClickDelete = () =>
    confirm("delete", postId, history, deletePost);

  const handleClickEdit = () => setEditClicked(true);

  const handleClickUpdate = () => {
    if (previousValue !== post)
      editPost(post, postId, "original")
        .then(() => setEditClicked(false))
        .catch(() => {
          confirm("edit", post, postId, editPost, function check(check) {
            if (check === "yes") setEditClicked(false);
          });
        });
  };

  const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
  };

  const previousValue = usePrevious(post);

  return (
    <Container>
      {errors.postDoesNotexist && <Redirect to="/404" />}
      {editClicked ? (
        <FormGroup>
          <label>Title</label>
          <FormControl>
            <input
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={post.title}
              type="text"
              name="title"
            ></input>
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.title}</span>
          </FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
      ) : (
        <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      )}

      {editClicked ? (
        <FormGroup>
          <label>Content</label>
          <FormControl>
            <textarea
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={post.content}
              name="content"
              rows="5"
              columns="30"
            ></textarea>
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.content}</span>
          </FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
      ) : (
        <p>{post.content} </p>
      )}

      {editClicked ? (
        <Button
          onClick={handleClickUpdate}
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="small"
          className={classes.button}
          endIcon={<Icon>send</Icon>}
        >
          Update
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <span>
          <Button
            onClick={handleClickDelete}
            variant="contained"
            size="small"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.button}
            startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
          >
            Delete
          </Button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Button
            onClick={handleClickEdit}
            variant="contained"
            size="small"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.button}
            startIcon={<EditIcon />}
          >
            Edit
          </Button>
        </span>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you wrapping your main app component with `<Provider store={store}>`?

Comment: Yes i am doing this

Comment: Have you tried to console.log payload you're getting inside reducer?

Comment: Yes issue only comes when i go to homepage. State gets saved in posts page .post page is for editing post. But once i direct to home page which displays all the posts ،state is restored to value at which it was decoded from token at the time of login.

Comment: Can you attach that particular page where you're unable to read store to get posts?

Comment: Ok i will ,but problem is not in reading from store, problem is in store itself, auth.posts changes back to value of jwt payload once i direct to home page

Comment: If you go directly to that post with url, you still get valid data or your store is trashed after navigating to home page / dashboard?

Comment: Yes it still is trashed even i go via url. It only holds once i remain in posts page. Once i direct to other routes state restores to value at which it was decoded. You can see App.jsx page at which it is decoded.

Comment: Oh, the issue here is that you're trashing your store each time you load app component/page. Basically, each time you land on app page you load posts from JWT, not from the store. Your logic behind this is not good. You should only run code under `// Check for token to keep user logged in` when you're entering the app page for the first time

Comment: My suggestion to you is to do post fetching as distinct action, and then call that particular action each time you land on desired page. By doing so, you'll always load fresh data from your API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was as luka pointed out, i was restting the state every time App was loaded. i changed the code of App.jsx to:

```
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/";
  }
}
```

I got the user id the first time when user is logged in and saved it as initial state in root reducer

```
// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = (userData, history) => {
  axios
    .post(`${url}login`, userData)
    .then((res) => {
      // Save to localStorage
      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      //Set user and is Authenticated
      localStorage.setItem("id", decoded.id);
      localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated", true);

      //set Posts
      dispatch(setPosts(decoded.posts));
      //redirect to home page
      history.push(`/users/${decoded.id}/home`);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      dispatch(saveErrors(e.response.data));
    });
};




import { SET_CURRENT_USER, SET_POSTS } from "../actions/types";
import isEmpty from "is-empty";

const initialState = {
  userId: localStorage.id,
  posts: [],
  isAuthenticated: localStorage.isAuthenticated,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        userId: action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
      };
    case SET_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I made the separate actions for fetching posts from Api each time home page loads. this solved my problem.